# What does 1'h1 mean in the RTL viewer diagram

Tags: verilog, quartus

[image: verilog code]

[image: diagram]

Just new to Quartus, from my understanding 1'b1 basically means 1 as input, but why it shows 1'h1 on the diagram instead of 1'b1 or just 1?

Comment: it's simply a fixed logic one the synthesize decided would fit well there:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means a 1-bit wide vector, with hex value 1. Quartus tied off that module to a logic high, as this was how it was tied in the port instance, as 1'b1.

1'b1 and 1'h1 are equivalent.